# Extended Session for transactions

Tags: java, hibernate, orm

What is 'Extended Session Antipattern' ?

Comment: Hogging the database. Doing so much work that when it committed the database is busy for too long: [see this thread](http://forum.springsource.org/archive/index.php/t-39523.html), it's almost all I can find on this. Search for "extended-session" and "anti-pattern", it's a long thread.

Comment: @Frayser: That comment probably should have been an answer.

Answer (score 5):

An extended (or Long) session (or ***session-per-conversation***) is a session that may live beyond the duration of a transaction, as opposed to transaction-scoped sessions (or *session-per-request*). This is not necessarily an anti-pattern, this is a way to implement *Long conversations* (i.e. conversations with the database than span multiple transactions) which are just **another** way of designing units of work.

Like anything, I'd just say that long conversations can be misused or wrongly implemented.

Here is how the documentation introduces Long conversations:

> #### [12.1.2. Long conversations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx)
>
> The *session-per-request* pattern is
>   not the only way of designing units of
>   work. Many business processes require
>   a whole series of interactions with
>   the user that are interleaved with
>   database accesses. In web and
>   enterprise applications, it is not
>   acceptable for a database transaction
>   to span a user interaction. Consider
>   the following example:
>
> - The first screen of a dialog opens. The data seen by the user has been
>     loaded in a particular Session and
>     database transaction. The user is free
>     to modify the objects.
> - The user clicks "Save" after 5 minutes and expects their
>     modifications to be made persistent.
>     The user also expects that they were
>     the only person editing this
>     information and that no conflicting
>     modification has occurred.
>
> From the point of view of the user, we
>   call this unit of work a long-running
>   conversation or application
>   transaction. There are many ways to
>   implement this in your application.
>
> A first naive implementation might
>   keep the Session and database
>   transaction open during user think
>   time, with locks held in the database
>   to prevent concurrent modification and
>   to guarantee isolation and atomicity.
>   This is an anti-pattern, since lock
>   contention would not allow the
>   application to scale with the number
>   of concurrent users.
>
> You have to use several database
>   transactions to implement the
>   conversation. In this case,
>   maintaining isolation of business
>   processes becomes the partial
>   responsibility of the application
>   tier. A single conversation usually
>   spans several database transactions.
>   It will be atomic if only one of these
>   database transactions (the last one)
>   stores the updated data. All others
>   simply read data (for example, in a
>   wizard-style dialog spanning several
>   request/response cycles). This is
>   easier to implement than it might
>   sound, especially if you utilize some
>   of Hibernate's features:
>
> - Automatic Versioning: Hibernate can perform automatic optimistic
>     concurrency control for you. It can
>     automatically detect if a concurrent
>     modification occurred during user
>     think time. Check for this at the end
>     of the conversation.
> - Detached Objects: if you decide to use the session-per-request pattern,
>     all loaded instances will be in the
>     detached state during user think time.
>     Hibernate allows you to reattach the
>     objects and persist the modifications.
>     The pattern is called
>     session-per-request-with-detached-objects.
>     Automatic versioning is used to
>     isolate concurrent modifications.
> - **Extended (or Long) Session: the Hibernate Session can be disconnected
>     from the underlying JDBC connection
>     after the database transaction has
>     been committed and reconnected when a
>     new client request occurs. This
>     pattern is known as
>     session-per-conversation and makes
>     even reattachment unnecessary.
>     Automatic versioning is used to
>     isolate concurrent modifications and
>     the Session will not be allowed to be
>     flushed automatically, but
>     explicitly.**
>
> **Both
>   *session-per-request-with-detached-objects*
>   and *session-per-conversation* have
>   advantages and disadvantages**. These
>   disadvantages are discussed later in
>   this chapter in the context of
>   optimistic concurrency control.

I've added some references below but I suggest reading the whole [Chapter 12. Transactions and Concurrency](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html).

#### References

- Hibernate Core Reference Guide

  - [12.1.2. Long conversations](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-basics-apptx)
  - [12.3. Optimistic concurrency control](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.5/reference/en/html/transactions.html#transactions-optimistic)